# Powershell: xml reading using XML-object not retrieving values if there is only one element

Tags: xml, powershell

```
param
(
   $xmlFile="D:\Servers.xml"
)
Import-Module WebAdministration
[xml]$xmlDoc = Get-Content -Path $xmlFile
for ($i=0; $i -lt $xmlDoc.root.Servers.Server.Length; $i++)
{
     write-host "Server $i =    " $xmlDoc.root.Servers.Server[$i].Name
}

#--------------------- XML ---------------#
<xml>
<root>
   <Servers>
     <Server><ip>10.2.2.1</ip><website>abc</website>
     </Server>
       ....
     <Server><ip>10.2.2.2</ip><website>pqr</website>
     </Server>
   </Servers>
</root>
</xml>
```

Powershell:
Problem:
Issue is if there is only one server node, "$xmlDoc.root.Servers.Server[$i]" does not work, as object consider as singular. Is there any way we can solve this, besides writing extra if. Basically i want to traverse thru xml file and for each server i want to do some operation.

Thanks,
Hanumant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't seem to have an attribute on the server object called 'name'.
I believe you could do the following to achieve your desired outcome:

```
param
(
   $xmlFile="D:\Servers.xml"
)
Import-Module WebAdministration
[xml]$xmlDoc = Get-Content -Path $xmlFile
$i = 1
foreach($server in $xmldoc.xml.root.Servers.server){
    write-host ("Server {0} =    {1}" -f $i, $server.ip)
    $i++
}
```

Alternatively, if you do not want to use the string formatting (but less readable in my experience):

```
param
(
   $xmlFile="D:\Servers.xml"
)
Import-Module WebAdministration
[xml]$xmlDoc = Get-Content -Path $xmlFile
$i = 1
foreach($server in $xmldoc.xml.root.Servers.server){
    write-host "Server $i =    $($server.ip)"
    $i++
}
```

Of course if you wanted to display the website of the XML node, then you can replace $server.ip with $server.website.

Comment: Essentially use foreach rather than an indexed array within a for loop. this way it caters for a single result, as well as many results.

Answer (score 0):

XPath query with [SelectNodes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes(v=vs.110).aspx) works fine, as it will return an [XmlNodeList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodelist(v=vs.110).aspx). It's a collection, so even no results will result just a collection with Length of zero. Like so,

```
# Create the XML doc via here-string
[xml]$d= @'
<xml>
  <root>
    <Servers>
      <Server>
        <ip>10.2.2.1</ip>
        <website>abc</website>
      </Server>
    </Servers>
  </root>
</xml>
'@

# XPath query    
$n=$doc.SelectNodes("/xml/root/Servers/Server")
# Print results
foreach($o in $n) { write-host "server" $o.ip "->" $o.website }
server 10.2.2.1 -> abc

# Negative test case
$n=$doc.SelectNodes("/xml/root/Servers/Srvr")
$n.Count
0
```